# Extracting an array from another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question regarding array.
I have an array shown below :

```
[1] => Arts and Humanities
[2] => Arts
```

I want this above array to be like :

```
[0]
    (
     [id] => 1 
     [field_name] => Arts and Humanities
  )
[1]
    (
     [id] => 2 
     [field_name] => Arts
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would simply be:

```
$array = [];

array_walk($oldArray, function ($value, $key) use (&$array) {
    $array[] = ['id' => $key, 'field_name' => $value];
});
```

This assumes `$oldArray` is `[1] => Arts and Humanities [2] => Arts`

Answer (score 0):

I didn t test this code, i wrote it on the row. but it can be something like this i think

```
$srcArray = array("Arts and Humanities", "arts");
$finalArray = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($srcArray); $i++)
 $tempArray = array("id" => $i + 1, "field_name" => srcArray[$i])
 array_push($finalArray, tempArray);
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly..thanks. just one thing i have added i.e srcArray[$i+1] because field name has index 1.

Comment: The other problem with this is when the array is NOT sequential. i.e. 1, 2, 4

Comment: yes but based on the current problem, the array is sequential